# Do I need to learn React to code in React Native?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, react-native

I'm about to learn React and / or React Native now that I master angular it seemed like the logical next step in my training.

From what I understood React Native could allow me to write an Android / iOS native app into one single project, however not possible to make 3 in 1 ? (Web + iOS + Android) ?

So, should I learn React + redux, and then only React Native or do I keep Angular for the web and react native for mobile devices ?

Thanks for enlighten me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you do need to learn React to use React Native. That's because the components used by React Native are actually React components. The 'trick' here is that React components can be passed either to React Native for native apps, or to React DOM for web apps.